# Selecting the text portion of an <a href> HTML tag through XPATH

Tags: c#, html, xpath, href

Consider the following:

```
<span>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('Send', 'ShowPackageDetails');"> Recall </a>
    </li>
</span>
```

I would like to grab the XPath to this element through the text value 'Recall'.

I know I can also select it by using:

```xml
//a[contains(@href, 'ShowPackageDetails')]
```

But other elements on the page also contain the same string in their href attribute.  I'd prefer to select based on the actual text instead of its attribute in this case because I know it's unique and I won't have to resort to index usage.

I've tried

```xml
//a[contains(@value, 'Recall')]
```

And other various combinations of `text()='Recall'`, but I'm not getting any results at all.

Comment: This is HTML, not XML. Look into using jQuery instead.

Comment: He could be using HTMLAgility pack or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` is for selecting attributes. Use the following instead:

```
//a[contains(., 'Recall')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

### Html

```
<span>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('Send', 'ShowPackageDetails');">Recall</a>
    </li>
</span>
```

### XPath

```
//a[text()="Recall"]
```

It may have something to do with the text being " Recall " and not "Recall". I removed the spaces in your markup.

Comment: Nice catch!  I included spaces in the XPath, and it showed up just fine.  But I think in this case, I'll be using the solution that @lwburk provided.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to parse a Html page that has been generated like in the example you provided, you should use the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). This is a C# solution (as I can see in your question's tag.

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("yourFile.html");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    //Check the text and do what you want...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the Html Agility Pack.  In the future, if we ever implement it, I'll be grateful for your suggestion.